# Possible Web3.js Security Issue

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, security

I have built an application that accepts erc20 token payments using the web3.js dependency, I followed the documentation of how to set it up properly. However, I was informed by a Solidity developer that it could not be used in production because whenever a transaction occurs I am unlocking the node and leaving my private key vulnerable. Has anyone run into this issue before? Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which documentation are you following? Are you hosting your own node that you're unlocking? The question should include code so we could see what the other developer could be referring to.

Comment: The question is quite generic. Someone tell you that something isn't secure. We don't know what are you deploying, we don't know who tell you that. If this person hasn't provided more details you should consider hiring someone that can provide auditing services.